# ImportError: No module named _thread

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror

Compiling python2 in vscode gives an error.
But when I compile python3 it succeeds.

```
print('test')
```

returns: **ImportError: No module named _thread**

```py
PS C:\source>  c:; cd 'c:\source'; & 'C:\Python27\python.exe' 'c:\Users\keinblue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '52037' '--' 'c:\source\test.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\Users\keinblue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from debugpy.server import cli
  File "c:\Users\keinblue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/../debugpy\server\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd  # noqa
  File "c:\Users\keinblue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/../debugpy\_vendored\force_pydevd.py", line 37, in <module>
    pydevd_constants = import_module('_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\Users\keinblue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 362, in <module>  
    from _pydev_bundle._pydev_saved_modules import thread, threading
  File "c:\Users\keinblue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 94, in <module>
    import _thread as thread;    verify_shadowed.check(thread, ['start_new_thread', 'start_new', 'allocate_lock'])
ImportError: No module named _thread
```

Comment: Weird, I also noticed this issue today, things were working fine until yesterday

Comment: Same here, I got the same error today

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is an issue with the vscode python extension version 2022.4.0

just downgrade to version 2022.2.1924087327 and it will work as it works for me now

Just follow these steps:

- Go to extensions.
- Click on Gear Icon for the installed extension
- Click on Install Another Version
- select the version you wish to install

[image]

Comment: Was not able to install older version inside docker container. It was getting installed in local machine. To install older version in docker container, install it from VSIX. First, download the VSIX for older version from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/2022.2.1924087327). Then you can either install from VSIX as suggested [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix) using command or [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/extension-marketplace/recommendations.png) through vscode GUI (3rd last menu).

Comment: is this fixed in v2022.4.1?

Comment: Just tested, it's not fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks so much. It fixes my problem. However, you might need to re-start your Visual studio Code.

Comment: Did they remove the ability to install another version ? If yes, is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

I think its the VS Code Python Extension. In VS Code select the Python Extension and select the Uninstall dropdown to install a previous version, the 2022.2.xxx fixed this issue.[install previous version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc6tc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same issue. These are the steps I executed to fix it.

1. Update the extension to the version `v2022.6.2`
2. Reload VSCode
3. Restart the involved application

It smoothly worked to me.